# what's difference between nodejs with browser about event-loop in below code?

Tags: node.js

```
async function async1() {
    console.log("a");
    await  async2(); 
    console.log("b");
}
async function async2() {
   console.log( 'c');
}
console.log("d");
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("e");
},0);
async1();
new Promise(function (resolve) {
    console.log("f");
    resolve();
}).then(function () {
    console.log("g");
});
console.log('h');
```

**nodejs** runtime output:  d a c f h **b g** e

**Google Browser** runtime output:  d a c f h **g b** e

why output different result?

Comment: Confirmed difference in behavior with more concise snippet: `async function a() {
  console.log('a')
  await b()
  console.log('c')
}

async function b() {
  console.log('b')
}

a()

Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  console.log('d')
})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think because NodeJS has own implementation of timers:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/timers.html

> The timer functions within Node.js implement a similar API as the
>   timers API provided by Web Browsers but use a different internal
>   implementation that is built around the Node.js Event Loop.

About event-loop in node: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Comment: While this information is true, I'm not sure how it's related. Both `g` and `b` by specification are scheduled to be logged in the same tick, that is, one tick immediately after the synchronous logging of `d a c f h`. I'm almost tempted to call this a Chrome bug, since the `await` in `async1()` was scheduled before the `.then()` call, which would normally result in the order `b g`.